# Jquery contains and display targeted div block

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery contains selector and I want to target the div I want to display when there's a match.

Here's my code

```
<div style="display:none" id="food">Spaghetti Banana Pizza</div>


<div style="display:none" id="result">Display this fruit!</div>
```

If there's match from every div = food (i.e. Banana), then display "Display this fruit!" div block.

Here's the code that's not rendering correctly -

```
<script>
$( "div[id^=food]:contains('Banana')").css( "display", "block" );
</script>
```

Error: it displays Banana. It should be the div=result.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain further? My unique div id=result.

Comment: instead of using `id="food"` you should use `class`

Comment: I've updated my code to have a single div block with id=food. So any idea how to target the div id=result to display? if there's a match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you only want to show the result div if they all contain `Banana`.

You need to check all of them against the total . Can use `filter()`

```
/* create collection of all possible elements so they can be counted */
var $food=$('.food');/* use class instead of duplicate ID*/ 
/* create boolean based on  matching counts*/   
var showresult=$food.filter(':contains(Banana)').length === $food.length;    
$('#result').toggle( showresult); /* toggle will show/hide depending on boolean*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique, you can use class instead of it, Then your code will be,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".food:contains('Banana')").length) {
        $("#result").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first you write your style in head, 
set the new attribute and value banana for div#food,for example data-toglle="banana" 
then you can use this:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var contain = $("#food").attr("data-toglle")
    if(contain == "banana"){
    $("#result").css("display","block");
    }
    });

</script>
```